# How to change the font for the disqus commenting

Tags: iframe, styles, stylesheet, disqus

I installed Disqus and it is making me crazy, I spent 5 hours yesterday trying to find a way to change the default font but it just does not work. 
I am using the Wordpress plugin available here : 
http://wordpress.org/plugins/disqus-comment-system/

I tried adding css in my style.css :

```
#disqus_thread{font-family:tahoma;}
```

but no luck, then I noticed it is loading the styles from `lounge_rtl.css` (since I changed to a different language) - also adding !important does not have any effect. any suggestion ?

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the CSS within the Disqus iframe since it's technically loading from the disqus.com domain. You do have two font options - serif and sans-serif - available to you in the Disqus admin, but nothing else can be changed at this moment.

Comment: This is unfortunate. I can't read comments at all when they're against black backgrounds.

Comment: The color scheme is auto-detected in most cases, but it sounds like it just didn't work on your site then. There's an option in your Disqus site admin settings to toggle the light/dark theme - try that.